# Is there a way to prefill the autocomplete entries in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos, autocomplete, excel-2011

I have a table with plant details.  Abbreviation, genus, species, common name etc.

This table is my reference table.

I have an inventory table where I can type in the code, where they are, how many, how big, etc.  It also fills in the common name doing a lookup on the first table.

Now, when entering the abbreviation I would like to have autocomplete pre-filled so as I typed the first few letters, all the matching abbreviations would show up.

Things I want to avoid:

- I do not want to use a dropdown list for 200 items.  Way too much scrolling.
- I do not want to use a mouse at all.  Enter a few characters, tab to the next field.
- If combo boxes worked on Mac like they do on PC, I could do a combo box and some clever VBA  This would still require clicking on arrow.  May be keyboard combos that would help though.

I tried putting the plant data table above the inventory table so that the abbreviation columns lined up.  No go.  Tables seem to keep isolated auto complete lists.

Is there a clever way to fill the autocomplete list from a named range?

Answer (score 0):

Put the long versions in the Table (and if inclined to do so, hide those rows).